# Issue with GridLayout

Tags: android, grid-layout

I am learning Android Programming. I am trying to develop calculator application using Android GridLayout. I am unable to display the last row in the numeric pad of the Calculator. Till Row Four in the code, I am able to see the layout properly. After adding the fifth row, I am unable to see the entire numeric pad layout. What's wrong with this layout?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background=""
    tools:context="com.akundi.kameswara.basiccaluculator.MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lLDisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/zero"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:textSize="100sp"
            android:background="#696969 "
            android:textColor="#FFF8DC"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gLNumpad"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lLDisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:rowCount="5"
        android:useDefaultMargins="false">

        <!-- Row 1-->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPower"
            android:text="@string/btnPower"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPercent"
            android:text="@string/btnPercent"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDivision"
            android:text="@string/btnDivision"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

       <!-- Row 2-->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSeven"
            android:text="@string/btnSeven"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEight"
            android:text="@string/btnEight"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNine"
            android:text="@string/btnNine"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMultiply"
            android:text="@string/btnMultiply"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <!-- Row 3-->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFour"
            android:text="@string/btnFour"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFive"
            android:text="@string/btnFive"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSix"
            android:text="@string/btnSix"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSubtract"
            android:text="@string/btnSubtract"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

       <!-- Row 4-->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOne"
            android:text="@string/btnOne"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
            android:text="@string/btnTwo"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnThree"
            android:text="@string/btnThree"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:text="@string/btnAdd"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <!-- Row 5-->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPlusMinus"
            android:text="@string/btnPlusMinus"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnZero"
            android:text="@string/btnZero"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPeriod"
            android:text="@string/btnPeriod"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEquals"
            android:text="@string/btnEquals"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>
    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Screenshot Till- Row 4

[image: Screenshot Till- Row 4]

Screenshot After - Row 5

[image: Screenshot After - Row 5]

Comment: Please past your whole layout file.

Comment: Full Layout file has been modified in this code

Comment: can tell me which keys do you want in last row ?

Comment: I want to add +/-, 0 , dot, equals keys in the last row. Is there anything wrong with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine there no problem in it.

The problem is Attribute `layout_columnWeight` is only used in API level 21 and higher.

I suggest you to use **android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout** t's backward compatible and supports weights.

So you just need to add compile **'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.1.0'** to your build.gradle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lLDisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#696969 "
        android:text="0"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textColor="#FFF8DC"
        android:textSize="100sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gLNumpad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lLDisplay"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    app:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    app:columnCount="4"
    app:useDefaultMargins="false"
    app:rowCount="5">

    <!-- Row 1-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPower"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="x"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnSpan="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPercent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="%"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDivision"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="/"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <!-- Row 2-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSeven"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEight"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="8"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNine"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="9"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMultiply"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="*"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <!-- Row 3-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFour"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="2"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFive"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="5"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="2"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSix"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="6"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubtract"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="-"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="2"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <!-- Row 4-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="3"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="3"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnThree"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="3"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="3" />

    <!-- Row 5-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlusMinus"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="+/-"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="4"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnZero"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="4"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPeriod"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="."
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_row="4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEquals"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="="
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_row="4"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: I am getting the same error, if I am replacing the android:text="@string/btnEquals" in case of the above solution also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbarHome">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:textSize="38dp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:text="0"
                android:background="#333"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="AC"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="%"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="/"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="7"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="8"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="9"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="*"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="5"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="."/>

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"/>


            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="="/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Saim thanks for your answer. However, I want to understand what is the mistake in the GridLayout which I have implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the grid layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gLNumpad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lLDisplay"
        app:columnCount="4">

        <Button
            style="@style/CalcButtonStyle"
            android:text="AC"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_columnSpan="2"/>
        <Button
            style="@style/CalcButtonStyle"
            android:text="%"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
        <Button
            style="@style/CalcButtonStyle"
            android:text="/"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
        <Button
            style="@style/CalcButtonStyle"
            android:text="7"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
        <Button
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalcButtonStyle"
            android:text="8"/>
        <Button
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalcButtonStyle"
            android:text="9"/>
        <Button
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalcButtonStyle"
            android:text="x"/>
        <Button
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalcButtonStyle"
            android:text="4"/>
        <Button
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalcButtonStyle"
            android:text="5"/>
        <Button
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalcButtonStyle"
            android:text="6"/>
        <Button
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalcButtonStyle"
            android:text="-"/>
        <Button
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalcButtonStyle"
            android:text="1"/>
        <Button
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalcButtonStyle"
            android:text="2"/>
        <Button
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalcButtonStyle"
            android:text="3"/>
        <Button
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalcButtonStyle"
            android:text="+"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Place your other repeating button definitions in the style `CalcButtonStyle`:

```
<style name="CalcButtonStyle" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
</style>
```